# Android TextView: How to place text above specific position in line/Setting height for ReplacementScan subclass

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to display song lyrics with chords in a TextView. For this, I need to place letters or symbols above a specific section of the main text. My idea so far is to subclass ReplacementSpan like this:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt;
import android.text.style.ReplacementSpan;

public class ChordSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    String chord;

    public ChordSpan(String chord) {
        super();

        this.chord = chord;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas,
        CharSequence text, int start, int end,
        float x, int top, int y, int bottom,
        Paint paint) {

        FontMetricsInt fm = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
        int space = fm.ascent-fm.descent+fm.leading;

        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
        canvas.drawText(chord, x, y+space, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
        FontMetricsInt fm) {

        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

}
```

This works nicely in placing the chord symbols above the text. However, I haven't found a way to adjust the line height when I add chords, so the chords get drawn across the previous line in the TextView. This code demonstrates what I mean:

```
package com.example.chordspan;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this.getBaseContext());
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        sb.append("The line above\n");

        int start = sb.length();
        sb.append("A line with chords\n");
        sb.setSpan(new ChordSpan("C"), start, start+2,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sb.setSpan(new ChordSpan("Am"), start+7, start+11,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        sb.append("The line below");

        tv.setText(sb);

        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

You'll see that the chords are aligned and get drawn correctly but overlap with "The line above".

Is there a way to achieve what I want, namely somehow adjust the line height for the line when drawing my custom Span? I haven't found any good examples of ReplacementSpan subclasses.

Alternatively, I'd be happy to receive other suggestions on how to achieve the desired effect. Maybe I'm thinking in a completely wrong direction.

Thanks for reading so far and for any help offered!

Answer (score 5):

After digging around for quite a while in the Android sources, I think I found the solution: The `ReplacementSpan`'s `getSize` method should not only return the Span's width as an `int` but can also alter the `FontMetricsInt` passed as an argument.

So with the following code the line spacing works as desired:

```
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
    FontMetricsInt fm) {

    if ( fm != null ) {

        int space = paint.getFontMetricsInt(fm);

        fm.ascent -= space;
        fm.top -= space;

    }

    return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));

}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the fm != null check is necessary.